# Difference between Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call and {}.hasOwnProperty.call.(eslint rule guard-for-in)

Tags: javascript, eslint

In the eslint rule [guard-for-in](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/guard-for-in) , use `for in` directly is incorrect. The good practice is

```
for (key in foo) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(foo, key)) {
        doSomething(key);
    }
    if ({}.hasOwnProperty.call(foo, key)) {
        doSomething(key);
    }
}
```

My question is when `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(foo, key)` and `{}.hasOwnProperty.call(foo, key)` will lead different result? Anyone can show a specific example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They'll never<sup>1</sup> lead to different results, which is why both of them are considered correct.

The object `{}` always inherits from the object prototype and has no own keys, so accessing the `.hasOwnProperty` method on it will get you what you want. And `Object.prototype` is a non-writable property of the global `Object` constructor, so it always refers to the object prototype as well.

Now, there are some cases where the expression does not do what you wanted it to do:

- Someone did overwrite the global `Object` variable
- Someone did shadow the `Object` identifier in your scope so that it doesn't refer to the global
- Someone did overwrite `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` with something else
- Someone did overwrite `Function.prototype.call` with something else

<sub>1: Obviously, the first two edge cases only mess with the `Object.prototype` reference, but they're still edgy enough to be ignored.</sub>

Comment: I think they should be same, but why eslint give the good practice example like that? Could you explain why? After all, the four cases you listed are too edgy to be considered.

Comment: Are you asking when they give a different result to `foo.hasOwnProperty(key)`?

Comment: They're just both acceptable "good practice" patterns. One is better to understand but can be easier messed with, the other is shorter but harder to read.