# Is there an ES6+ alternative to doing Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)?

Tags: javascript

The most bulletproof way of checking if an object has a certain key is:

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)
```

This provides certain guarantees: it will only evaluate to `true` if `key` is a **direct** property of `obj`, and it will work even if `obj` doesn't have the usual `Object` as its prototype (for example, if it was created with `const obj = Object.create(null)`).

But it's a mouthful.

Is there any new syntax/method in ES6 or higher (including polyfillable or Babel-compilable 'proposals') that gives the same guarantees, but in a nicer, more readable way?

Comment: Why not just alias it with a variable? i.e. `const iHaz = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` then use it like `const iDoHaz = iHaz.call(obj, key)`

Comment: Well, given that you almost never need to use this, what's the problem?

Comment: `const has = (obj, prop) => Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)` is the alias I typically use.

Comment: Yeah I usually write an alias. I just want to know if there's a nicer way available now, because if there is, then I don't have to keep writing aliases

Comment: The only ES Next feature I can think of that would shorten this at all is the bind operator, and its not much of a win here: `obj::Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty(key)`.

Comment: FWIW they've added `getOwnPropertyNames`, but it's still ugly when used to check for a single prop: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).includes(key)`. It would be nice if there was a neater way to check for a single prop, like `Object.has(obj, key)`

Comment: @callum actually I guess you could combine that with Bergi's answer and get `obj::({}).hasOwnProperty(key)` but that's a lose in terms of readability and I'm not sure how the precedence works out or even if the precedence for the bind operator proposal has stabilized.

Answer (score 14):

Update: [**`Object.hasOwn(obj, key)`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn) is part of ES2022.

---

I'm not aware of any syntactical sugar for this. But you shouldn't need to use this very often<sup>1</sup>, so writing it out occasionally shouldn't be too bad. An [equivalent shorter version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43268835/1048572) would be

```
({}).hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)
```

If you really need to use it more often, just define a helper function:

```
const hasOwn = (obj, key) => Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key);
const hasOwn = Function.prototype.call.bind(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty);
```

<sub>1: In most cases, you can omit the check, use `in` instead, or should be using a `Map` with its comfortable [`has` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has).</sub>

Answer (score 5):

[`Object.hasOwn`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn) was added to Object standard API. It is now supported on all major browsers.

Comment: Not supported on Safari except Desktop Safari Technical Preview. But it can be polyfilled.

Comment: Safari desktop and iOS added it March 2022.  
Edge & Firefox added it September 2021.