# Effective difference between Function.prototype.call.bind, returning a called function, and function assignment with .call

Tags: javascript, function, function-binding

As far as I can see, the following three approaches accomplish the exact same thing: determining if `Element.prototype` has native property `tagName`, irrespective of `Element.prototype.hasOwnProperty` being locally overwritten:

```js
  var ownsBind = Function.prototype.call.bind( Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty );

  var ownsReturnCallOfOriginal = function ownsReturnCallOfOriginal( obj, prop ) { 
      return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);
  }

  var ownsAssigned = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;

  var EP = Element.prototype;

  console.log( ownsBind( EP, 'tagName' ) ); // true
  console.log( ownsReturnCallOfOriginal( EP, 'tagName' ) ); // true
  console.log( ownsAssigned.call( EP, 'tagName' ) ); // true
```

In particular, what is the effective difference between `ownsBind` and `ownsReturnCallOfOriginal`, and what are some of the reasons for choosing one approach over the other two?

Comment: It's only different in [very weird edge cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43268835/1048572).

Comment: The reason why you would prefer the first or second over the third should be obvious